# Dynamically displaying buttons within a custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton, storyboard, subview

I want a custom cell to have a set of buttons, and the number of buttons I need depends on a parameter previously selected by the user, so I don't know the buttons I have to show until runtime (I know the maximum number of buttons I could have, though). I've been thinking of two approaches to do this:

1) To add the maximum number of `UIButton` directly within the prototype cell in storyboard, and hide or show them in code as I need. This looks easier, but I'd have hidden subviews not in use.

2) Programatically create and add the buttons at runtime, so I wouldn't have unused buttons. More code needed instead.

What shoud the best choice be?

Thanks

Comment: It would be better to make it by code, if you are concerning about memory issue. and in same time if you need to consider display time then it would be better to attempt 1st one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how much buttons could be in a cell.
In general second approach is best because of lesser memory footprint and possible faster 'UITableViewCell' reuse.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use the second option, as it gives you a higher control over the buttons, and you can modify and create as and when you require

Answer (score 0):

If the maximum number of buttons aren't very high, then I'd suggest you to go with the storyboard approach. This is because for the second approach you'll have to create buttons, and then destroy them in `prepareForReuse`. I'd rather take a little more memory footprint than have multiple button creations at run time (Potentially on scroll).